# how to return either instance of a class or an error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying out typescript and a library called TypeORM, and building some custom repositories for my models.

One of my models, `Buyer`, has a `BuyerRepository` with a method `createAndSave`.

If I want this method to return a `Buyer` if the save is successful, or an `Error('some reason')` if something goes wrong, should I be using `throw new Error('buyer already exists')`?

I guess what I am trying to do is something similar to Go:  `res, err := buyerRepo.createAndSave(buyer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular way is to throw error and catch them:

```
try {
   const res = await byuerRepo.createAndSave(...);
   console.log('buyer:' res)
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

You can use plain Promises too:

```
byuerRepo.createAndSave(...)
.then(res => { 
   console.log('buyer:' res)
})
.catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

To achieve something similar to Go:
https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/

Or if you like FP, this library will be usefull:
https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html